# Show Newsfeed from Sharepoint Blog on ASP.Net Site

Tags: asp.net, blog, newsfeed

My company has an asp.net site (Intranet). We'd like to incorporate a simple blog that can be shown on part of the intranet home page as a news feed. The actual blog doesn't need to be located within our site. User's would click through to the blogging site for details. I'm looking at setting a up a sharepoint blogging site and I'm wondering if there is a way to show a news feed from a Sharepoint blogging site, that we control, on our asp.net intranet site?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: RSS-feed could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Their are many ways to get this done, but in your case and simple & best way is using the RSS feed.

> You can enable any SharePoint list (including document libraries,
>   calendars, task lists, blogs and wiki libraries) to provide an RSS
>   feed. You have options to select which columns are provided in the
>   feed (like title, date and author) and you can set a limit for the
>   number of items and how old the items can be. Each RSS feed for a
>   specific list has a URL and it comes to the client as an XML document.
>
> References: How to manage RSS feeds:
>   http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA100214251033.aspx

You can read other options here:
[Integrating SharePoint with other portals and web applications](http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2007/04/05/integrating-sharepoint-with-other-portals-and-web-applications.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I've set up a sharepoint blog site on office 365 and I've got code that will consume the rss feed but I'm unable to make the web request with credentials.   I get the following error: "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden". I've tried both basic digest for authtype. Here is my code:

Comment: Dim strURL As String = "url" 
Dim MyRssRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(strURL) 

Dim mycache As New CredentialCache 
mycache.Add(New Uri(strURL), "Basic", New NetworkCredential("username", "pwd")) 
MyRssRequest.Credentials = mycache 

Dim MyRssResponse As WebResponse = MyRssRequest.GetResponse()
Dim MyRssStream As Stream = MyRssResponse.GetResponseStream()
Dim MyRssDocument As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
MyRssDocument.Load(MyRssStream)

Dim MyRssList As XmlNodeList = MyRssDocument.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item")